# How to write jQuery to hide only the first and second of multiple links?

Tags: jquery

I have a nested form, being created with cocoon gem and I am trying to write jQuery to hide links on only the first two of the nested form elements, the links in question each have the same class of `.remove_fields`.

The below code achieves this but results in the latest added `.remove_fields` link not showing either. Two questions:

1. Why does the below code still result in the last of the links still appearing?
2. The `:first-child` and `:nth-child` syntax commented out below won't pick up the `.remove_fields` link, I don't understand why, can you help me understand this too please.

Code:

quote.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hide_first_and_second_remove_empee_links() {
        var remove_links = $('.remove_fields')
        $(remove_links[0]).hide();
        $(remove_links[1]).hide();
        // $('a.remove_fields:first-child').hide();
        // $('a.remove_fields:nth-child(2)').hide();
    }
    $('#empee-form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    hide_first_and_second_remove_empee_links();
  });
  $('#empee-form').on('cocoon:before-insert', function() {
    hide_first_and_second_remove_empee_links();
  });
  hide_first_and_second_remove_empee_links();
});
```

_new_quote.html.erb:

```
<div id="empee-form">
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add employee', f, :employees %> <!-- Maybe needed for bootstrap to render properly; render_options: { wrapper: 'inline' }  -->
  </div>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :employees do |employee| %>
  <%= render 'employee_fields', :f => employee %>
<% end %>
</div>      
  <%= f.submit "Get quote", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

_employee_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<div class='form-inline form-group'>
    <%= f.input :first_name, label: "First name" %> 
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: "Last name" %> 
    <%= f.input :email, label: "Email" %>
    <%= f.input :gender, collection: Employee.genders.map { |k,v| [ k.humanize, k ] } %> 
</div>
<div class='form-inline form-group'>
    <%= f.input :date_of_birth, start_year: Date.today.year-16, end_year: Date.today.year-110 %>
    <%= f.input :salary %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove employee", f %>
```

I have just found that if i move the location of the `link_to_add_assocation` link to below the nested fields for, as opposed to above as it initially was, the behavior of the latest added nested form field's link not being shown is stopped? Code as below, can anyone help me see what's going on here?

```
<div id="empee-form">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :employees do |employee| %>
    <%= render 'employee_fields', :f => employee %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="links">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add employee', f, :employees %>
  </div>
</div>      
  <%= f.submit "Get quote", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code?

Comment: Sure, as above 